# laravel artisan app:name resulted in syntax errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am using Laravel 5 on a shared host. I have installed it ok. However on running:

```
/usr/bin/php55-cli artisan app:name 247
```

the laravel install broke. I tracked it down to app.php and the new name caused syntax errors. I got it working again by using Linux to do a global replace changing it back from 247 to App.

Does anyone know why? And how can I get artisan to work properly?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not Laravel nor artisan issue, but plain PHP syntax error.

PHP does not allow variable or class name to start with an integer. Same goes to namespaces. So your error comes from you app name being `247`. **First letter can not be an integer.**

Comment: thanks for that ruuter you right but it didn't work for me ... maybe it is looking for something somewhere and not finding it?? cheers

Comment: sorry, but "did not work for me" is not enough information to be able to help you. Please provides us the actual error you are getting. Then we might be able to help you further.

Comment: Hi hopefully this is a bit more revealing thanks....
247info.biz [Wed Jul 20 09:00:30 2016] [error] [client 66.249.78.250:60871] AH01215: #1 /home/sites/247info.biz/project1/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(629): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('matrix\\\\Http\\\\Ker...', Array): /home/sites/247info.biz/public_html/index.php

Comment: 247info.biz [Wed Jul 20 09:00:30 2016] [error] [client 66.249.78.250:60871] AH01215: #2 /home/sites/247info.biz/project1/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(697): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('matrix\\\\Http\\\\Ker...', Array): /home/sites/247info.biz/public_html/index.php

Comment: 247info.biz [Wed Jul 20 09:00:30 2016] [error] [client 66.249.78.250:60871] AH01215: #4 /home/sites/247info.biz/project1/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate in /home/sites/247info.biz/project1/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 734: /home/sites/247info.biz/public_html/index.php

Comment: 247info.biz [Wed Jul 20 09:00:30 2016] [error] [client 66.249.78.250:60871] AH01215: #3 /home/sites/247info.biz/project1/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(230): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('matrix\\\\Http\\\\Ker...', Array): /home/sites/247info.biz/public_html/index.php

Comment: huh, I'm sorry but no. Please add full stack trace and all error messages of Laravel application log and please include it to your question, not here in comments. This you gave now seems not to be Laravel application log, but apache error log maybe? Laravel writes its own app log in `storage/logs` dir.